# What does pipe `|` operator do in case expression of elm-lang?

Tags: elm

I have this following code snippet in my Elm code:

```
type alias Model =
  { content : String
  }


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Change newContent ->
      { model | content = newContent }
```

What does `{ model | content = newContent }` do?
Does it assign (bind) the value of `newContent` to `model` as well as `content`? Is that why the `|`  operator is placed there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pipe is not a part of the case expression. It's record update syntax, as described here: https://elm-lang.org/docs/records#updating-records.

```
{ model | content = newContent }
```

assigns the value of `newContent` to the `content` field in the `model` record.

Comment: Oh so it is accessing field `content` from model. Got it! Thanks @Ananth

Comment: It's not accessing the content field though. Since data is immutable in Elm, this pipe syntax returns a new record whose content field is updated to newContent.

Comment: You can read the expression above as something like "copy of model with content set to newContent" - just mentally mapping the "|" to "with" when I read the code works nicely for me.

Answer (score 8):

Read `|` as 'with'.

```
{ model 'with' content (set to) = newContent }
```